# How to get UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle content-length property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get asset size, which I download from remote server. I tried to get content-size from http header, but I can only access it when this request finishes else I receive null from www.GetResponseHeaders() function. I tried to use DownloadHandlerAssetBundle handler, but I cannot get content length out of it. If I write custom class which extends DownloadHandlerScript, I can then override this method

```
protected void ReceiveContentLength(long contentLength);
```

but then I loose DownloadHandlerAssetBundle methods. This is the code I am currently using:

```
    www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(url);
    //DownloadHandlerAssetBundle handler = new DownloadHandlerAssetBundle(www.url, uint.MaxValue) ;

    //www.downloadHandler = handler;

    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        AssetBundle bundle = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)www.downloadHandler).assetBundle;
        string[] scenePath = bundle.GetAllScenePaths();
        ...
    }
```

This page I was using when I tried to create custom downloadHandler https://unity.xiaomo.info/Manual/UnityWebRequest-CreatingDownloadHandlers.html

In update this is how I get currently downloaded bytes:

```
 www.downloadedBytes
```

So the question is, how can I get total asset size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs for `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle` it doesn't send any other data in the header. It's a special request just for Assetbundles and being able to extract the data before they're completely downloaded.

This method creates a UnityWebRequest, sets the method to GET and sets the target URL to the string uri argument. Sets no other flags or custom headers.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle.html

> This method attaches a DownloadHandlerAssetBundle to the
>   UnityWebRequest. This DownloadHandler has a special
>   DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.assetBundle property, which can be used to
>   extract the asset bundle once enough data has been downloaded and
>   decoded to permit access to the resources inside the bundle.

Are you wanting the size to inform on download progress or are you displaying a download size for the user before they start a download?

for download progress if you create a Async loader [AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync.html), you have access to a progress property.

If informing the user, try using a standard UnityWebRequest and retrieve a full request header with the content-length. Then replace the UnityWebRequest.downloadHandler with the DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.assetBundle before beginning downloading? (I'm not sure on this part, but it's what I would try.)
Perhaps call a standard UnityWebRequest get the content length, then replace this standard UnityWebRequest with the GetAsset version?

Comment: Thank you for response. I am trying to get asset size, to show, you have downloaded x mb out of y mb. I am trying to inform on download progress. I have access to progress float value, but I would like to show total size of downloading asset. As your suggestion it appears I would have to make 2 requests, one to fetch asset size, other to fetch asset itself. Does Unity have method for only receiving request header data, without downloading file itself? Also I believe, LoadAssetAsync loads already downloaded asset, so I receive progress on loading asset locally.

Comment: I found how to get only header, with this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Head.html , so I am going to make a request for header, than for asset itself, thanks again for help.